# What are all the steps to run a XCUITest on a device?

Tags: ios, coded-ui-tests

I can run XCUITests just fine on simulators, but when I try them on my device, the UITest icon is auto-clicked, and it fills the screen, freezes, then execution stops.  The bug readout is "Test target GreetrUITests encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted).

Things I have tried:
1. Gone into my phone's settings -> developer -> enable UI Automation. 
2. I don't have any cocoapods in my tests, only native XCUITests. 
3. I have a provisioning profile for my app, I am able to run the app fine.

I might need to add a provisioning profile to the UITest but I don't know how to do that.  I have also seen suggestions having to do with code-signing and paths, but I didn't understand the suggestions well enough to fix this.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my iphone 5s. I was using an iphone 5.  iPhone 5 was released in 2012 which was 3 years before XCUITests were released in 2015 with xcode 7.  I have xcode 9.0. Perhaps running UITests on iphone 5 is therefore deprecated.

Comment: XCTest framework is not related to device hardware, it will work on all devices running iOS 9 or later versions.